# Best way update from Pear::db to PDO,or PEAR::MDB2?

Tags: php, database, pdo, pear, mdb2

In my current project we use old library `PEAR:DB`.

We need replace this library on something better. But project in production,and very big,and many code from db layer use `PEAR::DB`.

What is the best way replace old code ,without  broken functionality?
Maybe write emulator class for DB? or install MDB2 and just replace all DB to MDB2?

Updated:Now for CRUD use doctrine/dbal component!

Answer (score 0):

PEAR's MDB2 package is a logical progression from the DB package, but even then it's considered very old now. You are probably better of using [Doctrine's Database Abstraction Layer](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html).